# pl/sql: Component 'X' must be declared

Tags: oracle, plsql

The below code appears to be ok. But now sure why it is throwing that error.

```
DECLARE
  CURSOR cur IS
    SELECT name, salary, deptname 
    FROM emp_dept_view;

    TYPE st IS RECORD( n VARCHAR2(30), s NUMBER(7), d VARCHAR2(30));
    rec st;
BEGIN
  FOR rec IN cur LOOP
    dbms_output.put_line(rec.n);
  END LOOP;
END;

ERROR at line 10:
ORA-06550: line 10, column 26:
PLS-00302: component 'N' must be declared
ORA-06550: line 10, column 1:
PL/SQL: Statement ignored
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Look here:

```
for rec in cur
loop
  .....
```

According to documentation: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e25519/cursor_for_loop_statement.htm#CJAIGGIA

> **record**
>
> Name for the loop index that the cursor FOR LOOP statement **implicitly
>   declares  as a %ROWTYPE record variable of the type that cursor** or
>   select_statement returns.
>
> **record is local to the cursor FOR LOOP statement**. Statements inside
>   the loop can reference record and its fields. They can reference
>   virtual columns only by aliases. Statements outside the loop cannot
>   reference record. After the cursor FOR LOOP statement runs, record is
>   undefined.

Emphasis mine.

It means that `rec` record in the `for ..loop` statement is local to this statement and it is of type `cur%rowtype`, but not of `st` record type. The identifier `rec` in the `for .. loop` hides the variable `rec` from the outer block. Within the loop you can use:`rec.name`, `rec.salary` and `rec.deptname`, but not `rec.n`.

Answer (score 1):

When you use cursor "for loop" Oracle automatically declares cycle variable. REC in loop is NOT the same as REC in declare section. In below example you can clear see that Oracle re-declares REC variable:

```
SQL> declare
  2   rec number;
  3  begin
  4    for rec in (select * from user_tables where rownum <=3) loop
  5      dbms_output.put_line(rec.table_name);
  6    end loop;
  7  end;
  8  /
DEPT                                                                            
EMP                                                                             
BONUS
```

Answer (score 0):

Another option is to modify the cursor to return the field names as you want them to be:

```
declare
  cursor cur is
    select name as n,
           salary as s,
           deptname as d
      from emp_dept_view;
begin
  for rec in cur loop
    dbms_output.put_line(rec.n);
  end loop;
end;
```

Share and enjoy.